# c# WindowsForm Point pointer value not changing

Tags: c#, pointers, point

As my teacher always told me: "in C# everything are pointers",

I am currently on a project where I use Windows Forms and the Point class that goes with it.

Example:

```
Point a = new Point(200, 200);
Point b = a;
a.X = 100;
Console.WriteLine(b.X);
```

As 'a' is a pointer, when setting 'b' to 'a' and then changing 'a.X' value, b.X value should change too right? But I still get 200 as a result.

I would like it to be 100 (keeping a link between them), is there any way to do this in C#?

Comment: "in C# everything are pointers" - not true. Sort of true for reference types (class), but definitely not for value types (struct). How is your `Point` type defined?

Comment: System.Drawing.Point is a structure, is that why? :/

Comment: Probably [System.Drawing.Point](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.point) which is a value type.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between a reference type and value type in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057267/what-is-the-difference-between-a-reference-type-and-value-type-in-c)

Comment: What if a define the class by myself? would it work

Comment: If you define it as class - yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've found out, value types are copied by value and not by reference.

However if you want an actual reference to this object you could easily just do it like this.

```cs
Point a = new Point(200, 200);
ref Point b = ref a;
a.X = 100;
Console.WriteLine(b.X);
```

Comment: Just tried it, and it works too, thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

defined as a class it would work, but not as a structure, overwriting the structure with an equivalent class do the trick.